# How many web pages can the Panels module handle?  What's the performance impact?

Tags: 7, views, panels

I'm creating new site in Drupal 7, and I must use about 400 panel pages with Views.  I'm wondering how many panel pages I can use in my site without affecting performance? Can Drupal/Panels handle 400 panel pages?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "400 panel pages"? If you have truly registered 400 menu-callbacks with the Page manager, you're insane ;) but it will have no effect on performance.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to believe that "Panels is slow". This is a misconception created by the fact that Page manager and Panels modules are complicated, and not easily understood.

Panels is actually [sometimes faster](http://www.codeenigma.com/en/blog/performance-panels) than core is on it's own.
And that's without utilizing caching, something Panels can do much better than core, because it allows you to do it from on a page by page basis, down to on a block by block basis.

At [NodeOne](http://nodeone.se), we build *all* our sites using [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), and [Panels Everywhere](http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere). I have yet to see a performance problem caused by the use of Panels itself. That said, you should consider using Caching, as a website utilizing Panels well is most likely a complex one. (I'm no longer with that business, but this remained true for as long as I was)