# Does using Views & Panels on every page will effect site performance (speed)?

Tags: views, panels, performance

I am building a community site. 
The site would have A LOT of data on it.

I thought about creating a lot of content pane with views, and use them with panels - for every page.

I will be happy to hear your thoughts about this idea.

- It will make my site much slower?
- Or it depends entirely on different things?   if so, I will be happy to get more information. I know I need to cache,  but I don't really know how to do that on the user's computers.

Thanks!

Comment: Does my answer over here answer your question? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21914/how-many-web-pages-can-the-panels-module-handle-whats-the-performance-impact

Answer (score 2):

Panels is actually sometimes faster than core is on it's own.

http://www.codeenigma.com/en/blog/performance-panels

And that's without utilizing caching, something Panels can do much better than core, because it allows you to do it from on a page by page basis, down to on a block by block basis.

Comment: Hey, thanks, you answered my question.
But, now i have another one - you wrote: "That said, you should consider using Caching, as a website utilizing Panels well is most likely a complex one". How do I make Drupal always use Caching?

Comment: @EB84, Drupal caching is a considerably large topic. Here's a good page that has links to various points -- https://drupal.org/node/326504